# What is the Bahadur-Anderson Algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, st.statistics, learning-theory

What is the Bahadur-Anderson Algorithm, and which book could one read to learn it?

Comment: It is explained on Wikipedia ;-) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raghu_Raj_Bahadur 

Comment: I am not asking for biography, but the maths

Comment: From the linked page "The Anderson–Bahadur algorithm[4] is used in statistics and engineering for solving binary classification problems when the underlying data have multivariate normal distributions with different covariance matrices." If you knew this already you might have written a more detailed question. 

Comment: Can you give me an example of a problem solved and steps involved? Thanks in advance and I really need to know it.

Comment: Sorry, no, I cannot; it is this first time I hear about this. I mainly posted this since from your question I had no clue at all what this was about, say is it Topology, Number Theory, or Statistics or whatever else. Thus, I searched for it and documented the information I found easily here to save others the same effort. However, if you just search for it, you will find sources on the web. For example, the book mentioned in an anwer, and some other documents. Also, somebody might give a detailed answer. To increase the likelihood of this happening I added some tags.  

Comment: IEEE has an article describing the classification algorithm (as one of many)
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1161983

Answer (score -1, accepted):

M. I. Schlesinger,Václav Hlavác̆, Ten lectures on statistical and structural pattern recognition, Springer, 2002.